# How to build a in-place Python Dict on a buffer?

Tags: python, buffer, mpi, shared-memory

I'm using multiprocessing.shared_memory to share a Dict among several MPI processes. While it is straightforward to serialize a Dict into bytes and copy it into the shared memory,

```py
import pickle
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

my_dict = {'k': 'v'}
raw_dict = pickle.dumps(my_dict)
dict_size = len(raw_dict)

# Create the shared memory
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=dict_size)
shm_name = shm.name
shm.buf[:dict_size] = raw_dict
```

it is puzzling how to convert it back to a Dict without copy.

```py
# Get the created shared memory by name
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)
# This is not working.
deserialized_dict = dict(shm.buf)
```

Is there a way to build a in-place object on a buffer in Python?

Here is the full code to help understand the question:

```py
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, resource_tracker


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

if rank == 0:
    my_dict = {'k': 'v'}
    raw_dict = pickle.dumps(my_dict)
    dict_size = len(raw_dict)

    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=dict_size)
    shm.buf[:dict_size] = raw_dict
    comm.bcast(shm.name, root=0)
else:
    shm_name = comm.bcast(None, root=0)
    print(rank, shm_name)
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)
    # This is not working.
    deserialized_dict = dict(shm.buf)
    # This would build a Dict using new memory.
    # deserialized_dict = pickle.loads(shm.buf)
    print(rank, deserialized_dict)

comm.Barrier()

if rank == 0:
    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
else:
    shm.close()
    resource_tracker.unregister(shm._name, 'shared_memory')
```

Comment: Why don't you use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict) on a [`mp.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager)?

Comment: As far as I know, the dict created by multiproccesing.Manager is hosted by a server process, which means the operations on it may introduce extra cost of communication and synchorization. In my code, the shared dict will only be used for reading. Therefore using shared memory can eliminate unnecessary communication and synchorization.

Comment: Have you actually tried the part in the comment: `deserialized_dict = pickle.loads(shm.buf)`? It works fine here for the given sample?

Comment: Using "deserialized_dict = pickle.loads(shm.buf)" works fine indeed. However, deserialized_dict is built on a new memory, and thus consuming more memory in additional to the shared memory. What I want is that all processes can access the Dict built on the same memory (i.e. shm.buf).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but imho that's not possible (without something like a `mp.Manager` etc.).